# what is the difference? with static and without

Tags: java

```
public class TypeMessage {

    public static enum GRAPH_ERROR {
        ERROR_INPUT, ERROR_GRAPH
    }


    public enum INPUT_TYPE {
        INTEGER, DOUBLE
    }
}
```

First enum is static, second is not static. I use `TypeMessage.GRAPH_ERROR` and `TypeMessage.INPUT_TYPE`.

Q: Does the fact that I wrote the word static in this situation has no effect?

Answer (score 2):

From [Java Language Specification 8.9:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

> A nested enum type is implicitly static.

so there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

For enums it doesn't matter. You can access both enums in the same way: `TypeMessage.GAPH_ERROR` and `Typemessage.INPUT_TYPE`.